# php mysql: select from database and populate form

Tags: php, mysql, populate

I would like to populate addresses for client from my db.
I use this code to select from db:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM peopleaddress WHERE peopleID=?");
    if ( !$stmt ) {die(printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($stmt) ) );}
else if ( !$stmt->bind_param('i', $peopleID ) ) {die(printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($stmt) ) );}
else if ( !$stmt->execute() ) { die(printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($stmt) ) ); }
else {
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $addressID_array = array ($row['addressID']); 
        $addresstype_array = array ($row['addresstype']); 
        $addressactive_array = array ($row['active']);
        $street_array = array ($row['street']);
        $city_array = array ($row['city']);
        $town_array = array ($row['town']);
        $state_array = array ($row['state']);
        $zip_array = array ($row['zip']);
        $country_array = array ($row['country']);
        $latitude_array = array ($row['latitude']);
        $longitude_array = array ($row['longitude']);

    }   
} /* end else */
```

and this code to display the form:

```
 <?php      
              for ($i = 0; $i < count($addressID_array); $i++) {
                  echo '<input type="text" name="street[]" id="" placeholder="street" value="';
                            if (isset ($street_array[$i])){echo $street_array[$i];}  echo '" />';
                  echo '<input type="text" name="city[]" id="city" placeholder="city" value="';
                            if (isset ($city_array[$i])){echo $city_array[$i]; } echo '" />';
                  echo '<input type="text" name="zip[]" id="zip" placeholder="postalcode" value="';
                            if (isset ($zip_array[$i])){echo $zip_array[$i]; } echo '" />'; 
                  echo '<input type="text" name="town[]" id="town" placeholder="town" value="';
                            if (isset ($town_array[$i])){echo $town_array[$i]; } echo '" />'; 
                  echo '<input type="text" name="state[]" id="state" value="';
                            if (isset ($state_array[$i])){echo $state_array[$i];} echo '" />'; 
                  echo '<input type="text" name="country[]" id="country" value="';
                            if (isset ($country_array[$i])) {echo $country_array[$i];} echo '" />'; 
                  echo '<input type="text" name="addresstype[]" id="" value="';
                            if (isset ($addresstype_array[$i])) {echo $addresstype_array[$i];} echo '" />';                       
                  echo '<input type="text" name="addressactive[]" id="" value="';
                            if (isset ($addressactive_array[$i])) {echo $addressactive_array[$i];} echo '" />';                                           echo '<input type="text" name="latitude[]" id="latitude" READONLY value="';
                            if (isset ($latitude_array[$i])) {echo $latitude_array[$i];} echo '" />';  
                  echo '<input type="text" name="longitude[]" id="longitude" READONLY value="';
                            if (isset ($longitude_array[$i])) {echo $longitude_array[$i];} echo '" /> <br>'; 
              }
              ?>
```

Problems: 
1) it only display one address, even if in db there are 2 addresses for the same client.

2) I'm pretty new at this. Am I doing it right or there is a fastest (less code) option to do this?
Thanks!!

Comment: in your while-loop, with each iteration, you assign a completely new array to your variables, thus overwriting the former value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is within your while loop:

```
$addressID_array = array ($row['addressID']);
```

This assigns a new array every time the while loops to the variables. These assignment lines should all be changed like

```
$addressID_array[] = $row['addressID'];
```

As for your 2nd question: it is not really answerable because we do not know the requirements you need to work against.

Comment: Thanks Shadow, I did it, but now the form is populated with: <br /><b>Notice</b>: Array to string conversion in.... and it refers to the lines where the code populates the form... !!

Comment: I think you left the array() function in your code as in @marinus' 1st version, which is incorrect.. Can you pls show me what you have tried exactly? Edit: which he has now corrected.

Comment: Yes, the display code is later in the text, after that the $stmt is closed.                   `<?php  
      for ($i = 0; $i < count($addressID_array); $i++) {
       echo '<input type="text" name="street[]" id="" placeholder="street" value="';
          if (isset ($street_array[$i])){echo $street_array[$i];}  echo '" />'; }`

Comment: This one ?   `while($row = $resultaddress->fetch_assoc()) {
   $addressID_array[] = array ($row['addressID']); 
   $addresstype_array[]  = array ($row['addresstype']); ... `

Comment: I  told you to remove the array() function out of the code, pls check my answer gain!

Comment: Do you have any reading / tutorial suggestions about arrays coding? when to use the $variable [ ] and when to use $variable = array ()?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php it's a long one, but is worth reading!

Comment: Hi Shadow, following your suggestion, I've wrote this code [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34936265/cant-echo-one-valueid-from-db-in-array], but I have a little problem. Could you get a look at it if you have a chance? THANKS!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the values in your array by doing this

```
$addressID_array = array ($row['addressID']);
```

instead of

```
$addressID_array[] = $row['addressID'];
```

**Update:**
Also, it would be a good idea to iterate over your data, instead of making an array of data and then reading that array again. Use this:

```
else {
$result = $stmt->get_result();
}   
// Then in display
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<input type="text" name="street[]" id="" placeholder="street" value="';
    if (isset ($row['street'])){echo $row['street'];}  echo '" />';
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marinus, I did it, but now the form is populated with: <br /><b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in....  and it refers to the lines where the code populates the form... !!

Comment: The display code is later in the text, after that the $stmt is closed. How can I use the while loop there?

Answer (score 0):

Check out : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Look down at the "Hexadecimal Conversion" part.  I put a short function to do SQL commands in there.  When you get the information back it will be in an array.  So if you used $row to get the information back it would be in $row[0][<Fields>], $row[1][<Fields>], and so on.

The problem with the above is - every time you do the "array()" it makes a new array.  So it wipes what you had in there before. :-)

Comment: Thanks Mark. I still have trouble to understand the array coding... anytime there is an array I have a panic attack :) !!! I hope I will get used to work with them!  PS Are you suggesting that my code is vulnerable to injection?!!!!