# Can't echo one value(id) from db in array after hit the submit button

Tags: php, mysql

This question follows this other one [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34848493/php-mysql-select-from-database-and-populate-form), but code and problem are different so I though it was better to ask another question. Hope is not a duplicate.

I have an edit form. This is the code to retrieve data from DB:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("
    SELECT
            phonetype.phonetypeID, 
            phonetype.phonetype, 
            phone.phoneID, 
            phone.countrycode, 
            phone.areacode, 
            phone.phonenumber, 
            phone.extension  
    FROM phonetype
    LEFT JOIN phone
    ON phonetype.phonetypeID=phone.phonetypeID
    and phone.peopleID = ?
");
if (!$stmt) {
    die(printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)));
} else if (!$stmt->bind_param('i', $peopleID)) {
    die(printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)));
} else if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    die(printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)));
} else {
    $resultaddress = $stmt->get_result();

    while ($row = $resultaddress->fetch_assoc()) {
        $phonetypeID_array[] = (isset($row['phonetypeID']) ? $row['phonetypeID'] : "");
        $phonetype_array[] = (isset($row['phonetype']) ? $row['phonetype'] : "");
        $phoneID_array[] = (isset($row['phoneID']) ? $row['phoneID'] : "");
        $countrycode_array[] = (isset($row['countrycode']) ? $row['countrycode'] : "");
        $areacode_array[] = (isset($row['areacode']) ? $row['areacode'] : "");
        $phonenumber_array[] = (isset($row['phonenumber']) ? $row['phonenumber'] : "");
        $extension_array[] = (isset($row['extension']) ? $row['extension'] : "");



        echo $row['phonetypeID'];
        echo $row['phonetype'];
        echo $row['phoneID'];
        echo $row['countrycode'];
        echo $row['areacode'];
        echo $row['phonenumber'];
        echo $row['extension'] . '<br>';
    }
} /* end else */
```

And this is the code for the form

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    echo '<input type="text" name="phoneID[]" id="" value="' . (isset($phoneID_array[$i]) ? $phoneID_array[$i] : "") . '"/>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="countrycode[]" id="" size="3" maxlength="3" value="' . (isset($countrycode_array[$i]) ? $countrycode_array[$i] : "") . '"/>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="areacode[]" id="" value="' . (isset($areacode_array[$i]) ? $areacode_array[$i] : "") . '"/>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="phonenumber[]" id="" value="' . (isset($phonenumber_array[$i]) ? $phonenumber_array[$i] : "") . '"/>';
}
```

**PROBLEM**:

When I edit the form, i.e. I enter a new phone number, and hit the submit button the form reload with all new data (areacode, phonenumber), but the new phoneID doesn't echo in the form.

BUT it echoes in the while loop that I use as test while developing.
AND If I retype the page address in the address bar, the new phoneID echoes in the form.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** 
as per cal_b suggestion if I test with:

```
var_dump($phoneID_array);
```

output when just loading the page is:

```
array(1) { [0]=> int(28) } 
array(2) { [0]=> int(28) [1]=> string(0) "" } 
array(3) { [0]=> int(28) [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(0) "" } 
array(4) { [0]=> int(28) [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(0) "" [3]=> int(29) }
```

output when adding a new phone:

```
array(5) { [0]=> string(2) "28" [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(0) "" [3]=> string(2) "29" [4]=> int(28) } 
array(6) { [0]=> string(2) "28" [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(0) "" [3]=> string(2) "29" [4]=> int(28) [5]=> int(58) } 
array(7) { [0]=> string(2) "28" [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(0) "" [3]=> string(2) "29" [4]=> int(28) [5]=> int(58) [6]=> int(59) } 
array(8) { [0]=> string(2) "28" [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(0) "" [3]=> string(2) "29" [4]=> int(28) [5]=> int(58) [6]=> int(59) [7]=> int(29) }
```

**SOLUTION:**

After looking at the var_dump and reading the php.net manual about arrays I understood what I was doing wrong.

In the SUBMIT code section, I load all the $_post in the arrays

```
    /*put all the entries into an arrays */
$phoneID_array = $_POST['phoneID'];
$phonetypeID_array = $_POST['phonetypeID'];     
$countrycode_array = $_POST['countrycode']; 
$areacode_array = $_POST['areacode'];
$phonenumber_array = $_POST['phonenumber'];
$extension_array = $_POST['phoneextension'];
```

and prepare the variables and loop the insert

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($phonetypeID_array); $i++) {
    $phoneID = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $phoneID_array[$i]);
    $countrycode = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $countrycode_array[$i]);
            ........................
```

I thought that when you use the same name for array, like u can do for variable, it just assign the new value(s) but apparently I was wrong. if you use the same variable name, it adds the new values to previous ones. (I still don't clearly understand why, and I would be grateful if someone would write 2 lines to explain that).

So the solutions are: 
a) unset the arrays before assign the same name to another array
or
b) simply use different names

PS Sorry, the problem was in the only chunk of code that I did not include in my (already long) question :(!

Comment: It would be nice if this were reduced to the minimal code to reproduce the specific problem.  NOTE: You should (in your "while" loop) `var_dump($phoneID_array);` instead of `echo $row['phoneID'];` - this would get you much closer to the actual problem.

Comment: @cal_b thaks, I did try your suggestion but I don't get it, sorry. Could you tell me what is wrong in my code? PS I'm never sure how to ask the question, if I post minimal code everybody says they don't have enough info, if I put long code it's too much... :) In the meanwhile I will try to cut down the code.

Comment: Where are your `if ` statements around the `isset()`conditions?

Comment: @Parfait it's a ternary conditional. You do not need an if. What order is the code executed in? It would be that you create the phone and id but before you could update, you may be doing the select.

Comment: @codeispoetry im not sure how you got in the loop because you never bind the value for `phone.peopleID = ?`, is it a typo

Comment: @Parfait The submit code is the first in the page, then I retrieve data from db and then the form

Comment: @meda sorry meda, I don't undertand what I have to correct

Comment: Well you prepare the statement and execute but where did you pass the variable

Comment: @meda cal_b suggested to cut some code lines, but if you look at the edits of my question u have all the code, included the `$stmt->bind_param('i', $peopleID)`

Comment: We cannot see the processing of the form input data and the insert statement, but my guess is that you run the select first to populate the form and you run the insert after that. This would result in the freshly entered data not being displayed immediatelly, but upon a refresh it is there.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop could be as simple as this:

```
$rows = array();
while($row = $resultaddress->fetch_assoc()) {           
   $rows[]=$row;
}
```

Then you print like this:

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $phoneID = (isset ($row['phoneID']) ? $row['phoneID'] : "");
    $countrycode = (isset ($row['countrycode']) ? $row['countrycode'] : "");
    $areacode = (isset ($row['areacode']) ? $row['areacode'] : "");
    $phonenumber = (isset ($row['phonenumber']) ? $row['phonenumber'] : "");

    echo '<input type="text" name="phoneID[]" id="" value="' .$phoneID. '"/>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="countrycode[]" id="" value="' .$countrycode. '"/>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="areacode[]" id="" value="' .$areacode. '"/>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="phonenumber[]" id="" value="' .$phonenumber. '"/>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Really helpful, I will for sure integrate your code and use it as a reference for future coding!!

Comment: For sure I'm using it now in this form and also use it as good example for similar situation

Comment: Thanks meda. I edited my question with the solution, it was in the arrays names...